# Data from the Firebase appear only when open the screen in the second time

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui

Can't solve the problem (don't even understand in what direction I need to google): have a StatsView with a summary of saved ("mastered" in the code) items –> when the user taps on the category they lead to the MasteredCategoryView with the list of saved items. The data is fetched from the Firebase. Fetching data fill the @State array with the async function, and then with the ForEach loop through the array I'm trying to display the list of saved items.

But how it works right now: when I open the MasteredCategoryView it shows the zero state –> open any other screen –> open the MasteredCategoryView again –> now the data is displayed.

What I'm trying to achieve is that when a user opens the MasteredCategoryView, when the data is fetched –> show the data on the MasteredCategoryView (btw, on another screen with a bit different logic, but there the data appear when the app gets the data from the server, have no idea why).

Below is the code for the class with all the functions, and two screens (summary and specific category).

Class with functions:

```
class QuestionModel: ObservableObject {
...
func getMasteredQuestionsArray(completion: @escaping ([Question]) -> Void) {
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            //handle error
            return
        }
        //Array of mastererd questions
        var masteredQuestions = [Question]()
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        //get access to mastered_questions collection inside users
        db.collection("users").document(user.uid)
            .collection("mastered_questions")
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    //handle error
                    print("DEBUG: Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                
                //Pick each element in mastered_questions colletction and append them to masteredQuestions array
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    
                    let questionId = document.data()["question_id"] as! String
                    //Go to collection questions and take a question with question_if from users->mastered_questions–>question_id
                    db.collection("questions").document(questionId)
                        .getDocument(completion: { (questionSnapshot, error) in
                            if let error = error {
                                //handle error
                                print("DEBUG: Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                return
                            }
                            
                            let masteredQuestion = questionSnapshot!.data()!
                            let masteredQuestionObject = Question (id: questionSnapshot!.documentID,
                                                                   category: masteredQuestion["category"] as? String ?? "",
                                                                   question: masteredQuestion["question"] as? String ?? "",
                                                                   type: masteredQuestion["type"] as? String ?? "",
                                                                   timestamp: masteredQuestion["timestamp"] as? Date ?? Date())
                            masteredQuestions.append(masteredQuestionObject)
                            
                            if masteredQuestions.count == querySnapshot!.documents.count {
                                completion(masteredQuestions)
                            }
                        })
                }
            }
    }

func getStatsObjects(masteredQuestions: [Question], completion: @escaping ([Stats]) -> Void) {
        let uniqueCategories = Set(questionList.map { $0.category })
        var statsList = [Stats]()
        
        for category in uniqueCategories {
            //print("DEBUG: Current mastered: \(masteredQuestions.count)")
            
            //print("DEBUG: Selected category: \(category)")
            //total questions in category
            let total = questionList.filter({ $0.category == category }).count
            let mastered = masteredQuestions.filter({ $0.category == category}).count
            //print("DEBUG: Mastered questions in \(category): \(mastered)")
            let stats = Stats(id: UUID().uuidString, category: category, mastered: mastered, total: total)
            //print("DEBUG: StatsObject: \(stats)")
            statsList.append(stats)
        }
        completion(statsList.sorted { $0.category < $1.category})
    }
...
```

Screen with the summary of all categories:

```
struct StatsView: View {
    
    @State var progressValueBehavioral: Float = 0.0
    @ObservedObject var questionModel = QuestionModel()
    @State var statsForMasteredQuestions = [Stats]()
    @State var masteredQuestions = [Question]()
    @State var totalQuestions: Int = 0
    @State var totalMastered: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
...
ForEach(statsForMasteredQuestions) { item in
                                ProgressCircleView(category: item.category, mastered: item.mastered, total: item.total)
                        } .onAppear() {
                            self.totalQuestions = self.statsForMasteredQuestions.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.total }
                            self.totalMastered = self.statsForMasteredQuestions.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.mastered }
                        } 
        }
    }
} .onAppear(perform: getMasteredQuestionsArray)
...


init() {
        questionModel.getData()
    }
    
    func getMasteredQuestionsArray() {
        questionModel.getMasteredQuestionsArray { (masteredQuestions) in
            self.masteredQuestions = masteredQuestions
            fetchMasteredQuestions()
        }
    }
    
    func fetchMasteredQuestions() {
        questionModel.getStatsObjects(masteredQuestions: masteredQuestions) { (masteredQQuestions) in
            self.statsForMasteredQuestions = masteredQQuestions
            //print("DEBUG: Mastered array from func: \(self.statsForMasteredQuestions)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

And the screen with list of items:

```
struct MasteredCategoryView: View {
    
    @StateObject var questionModel = QuestionModel()
    @State var masteredQuestions = [Question]()
    @State var filteredMasteredQuestions = [Question]()
    @State var selectedCategory: String
    
    var body: some View {
VStack {
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    if filteredMasteredQuestions.count < 1 {
                        VStack{
                            Spacer()
                            Image("empty_state")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                            Text("Oh damn, it's empty here")
                                .foregroundColor(.text_900)
                                .font(.system(size: 28, design: .rounded))
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                            Text("You'll see here all mastered questions")
                                .padding(.top, 1)
                                .foregroundColor(.text_700)
                                .font(.system(size: 19, design: .rounded))
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    } else {
                        ForEach(filteredMasteredQuestions) {item in
                            if item.category == selectedCategory {
                                QuestionForAnalyticsView(question: item.question, id: item.id)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } .padding(.top, 20)
                
                Spacer()
            } .onAppear(perform: getMasteredQuestionsArray)
}
    func getMasteredQuestionsArray() {
        questionModel.getMasteredQuestionsArray { (masteredItem) in
            self.masteredQuestions = masteredItem
        }
        for item in self.masteredQuestions {
            if item.category == selectedCategory {
                filteredMasteredQuestions.append(item)
                print("DEBUG: filteredMasteredQuestions count: \(filteredMasteredQuestions.count)")
            } else { }
        }
        print("DEBUG: getMasteredQuestionsArray: \(masteredQuestions)")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You don't call `getMasteredQuestionsArray` in the summary screen.  Also, you can use Codable with Firestore to simplify your code. And it  isn't very efficient to fetch all of that data each time a view appears. Views in SwiftUI are created many many times.

Comment: @Paulw11 could you please elaborate on the first sentence? I call the `getMasteredQuestionsArray` with .onappear, or did I do it wrong?

Comment: Not in `StatsView` or is your problem with the other view. In your question it would help if you referred to views by name rather than description.  Either way, fetching data in `onAppear` isn't a great approach as you will end up fetching the data multiple times.  It would be better to handle it in your model object

Comment: Also, idiomatically `filteredMasteredQuestions.isEmpty` is preferred to `filteredMasteredQuestions.count < 1`.

Comment: thank you @Paulw11, and sorry for the confusion. And edited the description to be more clear on the views. With the StatsView that was a mistake when I copy the code here, in the app it present the data properly. My problem occurs on the MasteredCategoryView. And thanks for advice with model object, will google it (so far, have no idea what it is)

Comment: You have one `QuestionModel` - This is an `@ObservableObject`, so it should have an `@Published` questions array rather than using `@State` properties in your view